# Glassfish 3.x start failed

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

i'm trying to run my java EE web application on Glassfish v3.x on Netbeans 7 but it wont work, and gives me the following error: Glassfish 3.x start failed.
i don't know what's the problem glassfish used to work fine before but then suddenly stoped working i unistalled netbeans and glassfish n install it again, but still the same problem.
here is the glassfish log:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 585ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 580ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 738ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 584ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 539ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]
GRAVE: Exception while visiting com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class of size 84805
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48188
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]
INFO: WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []
INFO: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.1.0 (FCS 2.1.0-b11) pour le contexte '/mavenproject1'
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/mavenproject1/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this was asked months ago but this question being one of the few sources i found in Google when encountering this problem, I think it'd good to share what bit i learnt:

I had the same exact problem and tried both things stated above. Still, my XML files didn't seem to be corrupted. In the end I found that the root of the problem was on the icu4j library which was, dont know why, among the dependencies in my project. Once I removed it, I was free of that error at last!

Should also be noted that Netbeans 7.0.1 (The IDE I'm using) also "uses" this library. I moved this library out of its original location just in case. NB continues to run without any problems so far.

Hope it helps someone else too!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! It helped me solve the same problem on a Liferay-Vaadin portlet I am working on. Just to add my experience, I had to completely delete my application from the 'applications' directory. Undeploying the app through the Glassfish Admin Console was leaving behind the WEB-INF/lib/ directory and contents (and thus the icu4j JAR).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed mine in this way. It seemed that my XML file for the domain was corrupt ( I have no idea how) but what i did is as follows:

Remove your current server from the server node( right click and remove), then make a new server, except when it says to pick a domain, type in your own domain name (EX. myDomain) and then set up the server.

Wait  for a few seconds, and bam, new XML file, not corrupt, and you should be able to run your server perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

That's strange... How it does say "startup failed" if it loaded your app? Take a look at the last three lines of the log!

I had some problems like this, but all I needed is to right-click on the GF server node on "Services" tab and "refresh" it. Usually NB consider a slow GF startup as "failed".

Comment: thanks for your anwser, the message above is all what i had on the log, i already tryed refresh but still not working :(

Comment: yesterday i installed Netbeans 6.9 and glassfish worked just fine, and today when i tryed to continue my work, glassfish refused to start again!! i don't get it! :s

Comment: remove everything you created on GF (datasources, apps, connectors, pools, etc) - just to check if the problem is the installation or something you added!

Comment: i unistall it and install it again, and it's working at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Another answer which is possible now if using Java 8, but not at the time the OP asked, is that the server code contains lambdas.  If you do have lambdas in your code, try to replace them with anonymous inner classes and your class(es) that were affected should now be good to go.